# Use Android device as a headset for another device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, headset

When I use Bluetooth on my computer, I have a choice of a few different types of devices to look for. One choice is "headset".

I want to make an application that will connect to another device as though it is nothing but a headset. So the audio and microphone will route from the Android phone to the other device.

Is this possible within the Bluetooth API? If so, is the Bluetooth Chat example the best thing to start with for something like this? Most of the information I can find deals with the opposite situation (using an actual headset with an Android device.)

Comment: i am confused by your question, do you want the android device to act like a headset ?

Comment: In combination with smartcam, it would make a great wireless webcam+mic for skype.

Comment: @fmjrey: or you can just install skype on android

Answer (score 2):

Most phones are only bluetooth masters, cannot act as devices... I am afraid you are out of luck... Unless what you are doing is on a completely different device and in that case, no, the API will not handle that case.

Comment: Phones prefer to be master - they can be slave also sometime. Anyway being a master or slave has nothing to do with what it can or cannot do, the roles in bluetooth are symmetrical - it is the supported profiles that determines what it can or cannot do

Comment: This is a 2010 answer. In 2014 the answer is still NO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717902/does-android-kitkat-allows-devices-that-support-bluetooth-le-to-act-as-a-periphe). In the future, perhaps, or with some kind of hack magic or specific APIs...