# Does Android API 20 allows devices that support Bluetooth LE to act as a peripheral device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the below code to set the Android device act as peripheral, but it does not seem like working. Do you know if peripheral mode is supported with API 20?

```
BluetoothGattServer mGattServer;
public void startPeripheralGattServer() {
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

        mGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(getApplicationContext(), new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId,
                    int offset, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

                    if (mGattServer != null) {
                        mGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, offset, new byte[] { '1' });
                    }
                }
            });

        UUID serviceUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
        UUID characteristicUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
        UUID descriptorUUID = UUID.randomUUID();

        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(characteristicUUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
        characteristic.setValue(77, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(descriptorUUID,    
                BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);

        characteristic.addDescriptor(descriptor);

        BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(serviceUUID, 
                BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
        service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);

        mGattServer.addService(service);
    }
```

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717902/does-android-kitkat-allows-devices-that-support-bluetooth-le-to-act-as-a-periphe?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [Google I/O video for Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fZThdNbHcQ), peripheral mode will become available from Android API 20 (Android L) and above.

Answer (score 2):

The peripheral mode is supported with API 20. However, to transmit as a peripheral mode, Android 5.0+ and firmware supporting Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Mode are required. As of December 2014, only Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 devices are known to have firmware that supports Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Mode.

Please [click here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) get more information

Answer (score 0):

They will be available from API Level 21

[BLE Peripheral APIs avaliable from API Level 21](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html)